# Better server to client communication mechanism over HTTP

Tags: http, internet, client-server

I have a single server with several clients. I want to push messages to a particular client at a given time. Clients should not polling to the server. what are good patterns and practices to solve this problem?

Comment: Keep connections alive, and periodically sending keep-alive packets (sparingly enough) just to prevent the connection from closing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a technique often referred to long-polling or [comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), which allows to implement a ["push"-based event/update system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

### Principle

The principle is rather simple:

1. client sends a request to server and keeps connections alive;
2. server keeps a handle on the connection and waits;
3. when updates are available, server sends back data to client;
4. (depending on client-side tech) client may need to send a new request.

This way the clients don't poll regularly. However, that implies that a significant number of connections might be kept alive at any single given time, so make sure you understand 
the implications of this approach for your server.

### How to Implement It?

So, the underlying principle remains the same no matter what your platform is: as long as you can send an HTTP request and wait for the response synchronously or asynchronously, you have a way to implement long-polling.

#### Heavy Clients

With most programming languages aimed at developing desktop solutions (or "heavy" clients), you'd usually resort to your usual network tools: sockets.

#### Lightweight/Rich Clients

If we're talking about a rich web-client to build in a browser-based solution, you have the option to:

- use your usual [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object (the server will only reply once it's got something to send back, at which point the client will either re-initiate another connection or use a spare one if it opened multiple ones to ensure there's always multiple channels opened at hand),
- or to use `<script>` tags that query a URL sending back a payload wrapped in a call to function defined in the client's context (see [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)),
- or to use [`WebSocket`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) API introduced with [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5),
- or a variation of the above or using an external tool (Java Applet, Flash, etc...) to achieve the same effect.

Beware that, as is often the case with web techs, cross-browser support is going to require extensive testing, and you may be forced to use a combination of the above techniques if you target hostile browser market shares...

Comment: +1. The only thing which is missing from the answer, IMO, is the explicit mention of web sockets.

Comment: @MainMa: True, WebSockets are **one** of the options to do this (and probably the best if you have the freedom of using them, actually).

Comment: @MainMa: edited.

Comment: @KanishkaDilshan: Great. Glad it helped. Looks like you were just one google search away from it though.